# Показывать дату у общих вопросов в списке вопросов

Tags: предложение, вопросы, общие-сообщения, список-вопросов

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Frequent

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для русского сообщества это полезно